# MSXML: How does one programmatically get the error text for failed transforms?

Tags: winapi, xslt, msxml

XMLNotepad provides the following text (for example) when a transform fails:

> Error Transforming XML
>   The variable
>   or parameter
>   'saturated-background-color' was
>   duplicated with the same import
>   precedence.

How would I go about getting this error text programmatically?  My code looks like this:

```
CComPtr<IXSLTemplate> tmpl;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_XSLTemplate, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IXSLTemplate, (void**)&tmpl);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    hr = tmpl->putref_stylesheet(xslt_doc);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    // Huzzah; do stuff.
    } else {
    // How do I get the error text?  I want to log it!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `IXSLTemplate` supports `IErrorInfo` (AFAIK, it does), then you can query that for additional information.

(jeffamaphone clued me in on the proper way to get this - using the `GetErrorInfo()` API:)

```
CComPtr<IErrorInfo> error;
if (SUCCEEDED( GetErrorInfo(0, &error) ) && error)
{
   // call IErrorInfo::GetDescription(), etc.
}
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't seem to support that interface.  QueryInterface() returns E_NOINTERFACE.

Comment: That's a shame. You could try IXMLDOMParseError, but i'm pretty sure that's only used by the DOMDocument classes.

Comment: I suspect the right way to get the IErrorInfo pointer is not through QueryInterface, but through the GetErrorInfo() COM API itself.  I've implemented that, and will see if it works.

Comment: Interesting... I didn't even know about that. Post an answer if it works!

Comment: Marking as answer... you were pretty close.  Instead the solution is to call the GetErrorInfo() API directly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221032.aspx

Comment: @jeffamaphone: excellent work, i've updated the example to reflect this.